# How to achieve state normalization in Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I am developing an app also using Vuex and just hit a situation where dealing with nested objects will be a pain, so I am trying to normalize(flatten) the state as much as possible like the example below:

```
users: {
    1234: { ... },
    46473: { name: 'Tom', topics: [345, 3456] }
},
userList: [46473, 1234]
```

My question is: **What's the "best" way to achieve the above when your API response looks like this**:

```
data: [
    {id: 'u_0001', name: 'John', coments: [{id: 'c_001', body: 'Lorem Ipsum'}, {...}],
    {id: 'u_0002', name: 'Jane', coments: [{id: 'c_002', body: 'Lorem Ipsum'}, {...}],
    {...}
]
```

Assuming for the sake of the example that `comments` is a submodule of `users`:

**Option 1:**

```
// action on the user module
export const users = ({ commit, state }, users) => {
    commit(SET_USERS, users)
    commit('comments/SET_COMMENTS', users)
}


// mutation on the user module
[types.SET_USERS] (state, users) {
     state.users = users.reduce((obj, user) => {
         obj[user.id] = {
             id: user.id, 
             name: user.name,
             comments: user.comments.map(comment => comment.id)
         } 
         return obj
     }, {})
    state.userIds = users.map(user => user.id)
},


// mutation on the comments module
[types.SET_COMMENTS] (state, users) {
    let allComments = []
    users.forEach(user =>  {
        let comments = user.comments.reduce((obj, comment) => {
            obj[comment.id] = comment
            return obj
        }, {})
        allComments.push(comments)
    })

   state.comments = ...allComments
},
```

IMO this option is good because you don't have to worry about resetting the state every time you change pages(SPA/Vue-Router), avoiding the scenario where for some reason `id: u_001` no longer exists, because the state is overridden every time the mutations are called, but it feels odd to pass the `users array` to both mutations.

**Option 2:**

```
// action on the user module
export const users = ({ commit, state }, users) => {
    // Here you would have to reset the state first (I think)
    // commit(RESET)

    users.forEach(user => {
        commit(SET_USER, user)
        commit('comments/SET_COMMENTS', user.comments)
    })
}


// mutation on the user module
[types.SET_USER] (state, user) {
    state.users[user.id] = {
        id: user.id, 
        name: user.name,
        comments: user.comments.map(comment => comment.id)
    }  
    state.userIds.push(user.id)
},


// mutation on the comments module
[types.SET_COMMENTS] (state, comments) {
    comments.forEach(comment => {
        Vue.set(state.comments, comment.id, comment)
    })
    state.commentsIds.push(...comments.map(comment => comment.id)
},
```

In this situation there's the need to reset state or you will have repeated/old values every time you leave and re-renter the page. Which is kind of annoying and more susceptible to bugs or inconsistent behaviors.

**Conclusion**
How are you guys tackling such scenarios and advices/best practices? Answers are very appreciated since I'm stuck on these things.

Also, I'm trying to avoid 3r party libraries like the Vue ORM, normalizr, etc. because the needs are not that complex.

Thank you,

PS: The code might have errors since I just wrote it without testing, please focus on the big picture.

Comment: I like option #1 but that's just my opinion. Do you have an actual problem with either approach that you need help with?

Comment: Currently, I've implemented the 2nd option, then realized the need to reset the state in probably every situation there's nested data from the API, so I created a mutation at the root level that receives two arguments: a string with a module name(eg: 'users') and the default state for that module as a function, loop through it eg: ```for (const key in defaults) { Vue.set(state[module], key, defaults[key]) }```
Bottom line is this gets very tricky to access nested modules and a RESET mutation in every module is not very DRY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, To avoid Accidental Complexity in the state below are the points which need to be taken care while doing state normalization.

As mentioned under official Redux [docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape#designing-a-normalized-state)

> 1. Each type of data gets its own "table" in the state.
> 2. Each "data table" should store the individual items in an object, with the IDs of the items as keys and the items themselves as the values.
> 3. Any references to individual items should be done by storing the item's ID.
> 4. Arrays of IDs should be used to indicate ordering.

Now with the example above, to remove redundancy from the data. You can use each table for each information such as `users`, `comments` and so on.

```
{
  'users': {
    byId : {
      "user1" : {
        username : "user1",
        name : "User 1",
      },
      "user2" : {
        username : "user2",
        name : "User 2",
      },
      ...
    },
    allIds : ["user1", "user2", ..]
  },
  'comments': {
    byId : {
      "comment1" : {
        id : "comment1",
        author : "user2",
        body: 'Lorem Ipsum'
      },
      "comment2" : {
        id : "comment2",
        author : "user3",
        body: 'Lorem Ipsum'
    },
    allIds : ["comment1", "comment2"]
  }
}
```

By doing so, we can make sure that more components are connected and responsible for looking and maintaining their own data set instead of every component has a large data set and passing data to the chilren component.

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Since data have been normalize as per the component, pass the entities from the parent component with single action and as a part of normalization, below benefits can be achieved.

> 1. Faster data access, no more iterating over arrays or nested objects.
> 2. Loose coupling between components.
> 3. Each component has its own place in the store, hence there is a single point of truth.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but your answer would be more suited to: is there any way to avoid nested data in vuex. The normalization tips I already know. My question is the next step as how to actually do it. Imagine having something like: users > comments > tags (nested data) in your user module action would you be firing 3 mutations always passing the users array and inside each one loop until reach the desired data or would you first loop through the users, fire a mutation to set each user, then one mutation to set all the comments and finally loop through the comments and fire a mutation to set all the tags?

Comment: Updated answer. happy to add if more clarification requires.